# Running Time Machine only 1 time a day at 02:00am?

Tags: time-machine, macos

I must say that Time Machine is pretty useful, and it saved me a couple of times. The problem is it seems running all the times, and slowing the system down pretty often.

Is there a way/tool to run Time Machine only once a day, say 02:00am. And, it would be better if the Time Machine wakes the Mac up and after it's done with the backup, go to sleep again.

### ADDED

I installed and ran the 'Timemachine Editor' as advised, but it doesn't work. I mean, even though I set the timemachine to run 02:00am, it just runs every hour.

I use Snow Leopard 10.6.4. Is there anything that I missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you said that [Time MAchine Editor](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/26704/timemachineeditor) didn't work fine for you then I search in web and find :  [TimeMachineScheduler](http://www.klieme.com/TimeMachineScheduler.html) it disables the automatic backup function of Time Machine and installs its own launchd daemon.

[image]

[Time Machine Editor](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/26704/timemachineeditor) (**free** software) allows you to specify a schedule for Time Machine to run. it changes the one-hour interval of Time Machine backups. You can change the interval or decide to make ***daily***, ***weekly*** and ***monthly*** backups.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/) instead.  It uses the same underlying stuff as Time Machine.

You can set a scheduled task for 2am that does an Incremental Backup with the "archive deleted or modified files" option checked.

Here's what mine looks like... create something like this:

[image: setup]

Then click save task.  It should look like this in the saved tasks window:

[image: tab 1]

[image: tab 2]

[image: tab 3]

Answer (score 0):

Time Machine Backup Scheduler does scheduling backup:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/time-machine-backup-scheduler/id668331139?mt=12